# Hindley-Milner algorithm: using types to ensure bindings are applied

Tags: haskell, types, unification

I am implementing the Hindley-Milner type inference algorithm, following the tutorials of [Mark Jones](http://web.cecs.pdx.edu/~mpj/thih/) and [Oleg Kiselyov](http://okmij.org/ftp/Computation/Computation.html#teval). Both of these have an "apply bindings" operation with a type roughly of the form

```
applyBindings :: TyEnv -> Type -> Type
```

which applies the `tyvar -> ty` bindings in `TyEnv` to the given `Type`. I have found it a common mistake in my code to forget to call `applyBindings`, and I get no help from Haskell's type system, since `ty` has the same type as `applyBindings tyenv ty`. I am looking for a way to enforce the following invariant in the type system:

> when doing type inference, bindings must be applied before returning a 'final' result

When doing type inference for a monomorphic object language, there is a natural way to enforce  this, as implemented in wren ng thornton's [unification-fd package](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unification-fd): we define two datatypes for `Type`s:

```
-- | Types not containing unification variables
type Type = ...          -- (Fix TypeF) in wren's package

-- | Types possibly containing unification variables
type MutType = ...       -- (MutTerm IntVar TypeF) in wren's package
```

and give `applyBindings` the type

```
-- | Apply all bindings, returning Nothing if there are still free variables
-- otherwise just
applyBindings :: TyEnv -> MutType -> Maybe Type
```

(this function is actually `freeze . applyBindings` in unification-fd). This enforces our invariant - if we forget to `applyBindings`, then we will get a type error.

This is the kind of solution I am looking for, but for object languages with polymorphism. The above approach, as it stands, doesn't apply, since our object-language types may have type variables -- indeed, if there variables free after applying bindings, we don't want to return `Nothing`, but we we want to generalise over these variables.

Is there a solution along the lines I describe, i.e. one which gives `applyBindings` a different type from `const id`? Do real compilers use the same punning (between unification variables and object-language type variables) that Mark's and Oleg's tutorials do?

Comment: When you say generalise over those variables, do you mean you want to not get back a type, but a type scheme? i.e., conceptually a function from variables to a type? In that case, you should be able to make a conceptual distinction between free type variables, and type variables quantified by, e.g., a forall, just as one distinguishes at the value level between syntactic fragments containing free variables, and expressions where all variables are introduced by lambdas.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm taking a stab in the dark here, because I think there may be other problems with the solution you propose, but I can address at least one difficulty:

- Your type checker should have *different* representations for *unification type variables* and *object-language type variables*.

This variation is not difficult to implement, and in fact I think the GHC type checker worked this way, at least at one time.  You might want to check the paper [Practical Type Inference for Arbitrary-Rank Types](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/simonpj/papers/higher-rank/); the appendix contains a lot of very helpful code.

Comment: Great, thanks for that link - it made quite explicit to me the distinction between meta-language type variables and object-language type variables. I notice that the authors make no distinction in the type system between "types which could have `MetaTv`s in them" and "types which can't" (for instance, `quantify :: [MetaTv] -> Rho -> Tc Sigma` should return a type without any `MetaTv`s, but its type doesn't say so). Are there any papers which make such a distinction?